Apply async batching to Dataframe.apply()?
I have already checked out this url:
Can I execute a function in "apply" to pandas dataframe asynchronously?(Can I execute a function in "apply" to pandas dataframe asynchronously?)
However, along the same lines, I have nearly 1000000 records for which I have to fire requests and store them in an existing dataframe.
Here is a sample code reduced to its basics for context:
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector

DATABASE1 = ["list of connection dicts"]
SQL_QUERY = "select query"

def fetch_service_status_details(row):
    user_id = row["user_id"]
    service_id = row["service_id"]

    url = SERVICE_URL + "/" + service_id + "/" + user_id
    resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
    row["resp_code"] = resp.status_code
    if resp.ok:
        row["has_active_service"] = (
            resp.json()["data"]["has_active_service"]
            if resp.json()["success"]
            else "NO_DATA"
        )
    else:
        row["has_active_service"] = (
            "FAILED_TO_FETCH::" + str(resp.status_code) + "::" + str(resp.text)
        )
    return row

def connection(connection_dct):
    db = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=connection_dct["host"], user=connection_dct["user"], password=connection_dct["password"], database=connection_dct["database"]
    )
    return db

def generate_df():
    data = pd.DataFrame(columns=["service_id", "user_id"])
    for db in DATABASE1:
        conn = connection(db)
        temp = pd.read_sql(SQL_QUERY, conn)
        data = pd.concat([data, temp])
    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = generate_df()
    data = data.apply(fetch_service_status_details, axis=1)
    rest of calculative operations on df


How can I apply batching to the apply function so that it fires requests at 30 RPS to go through 1000000 records minimum.
I initially tried going row by row, however, after a lot of execution and study, I found out that it is an idiotic thing to iterate over rows in pandas.

You have data = data.apply(fetch_mandate_status_details, axis=1) but fetch_mandate_status_details is undefined. Did you mean fetch_service_status_details?

Assuming RPS is requests per second, are you sure SERVICE_URL will allow or can support that rate?

Yes - Pandas will always call the apply function itself synchronously - but if the ".apply" call is made, from your code, in an asynchronous context, the code inside apply can create a new asynchronous task, that will run concurrently with other tasks created in the same "apply" operation.
Some care has to be taken, however, that the "row" object itself is re-used across an "apply" operation, therefore expressions like row["resp_code"] = resp.status_code would always affect the same row (usually the last one) in the dataframe).
I found out that using the row.name attribute, and otherwise conveying the dataframe into the co-routine created by apply, one can update the df lazily, in an async concurrent mode. Of course, instead of requests you'd better switch to an asyncio-native HTTP client lib, such as httpx  -however, even as it is, one can run these async in a thread-pool executor:
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from functools import partial
import asyncio
import contextvars

import requests
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector

DATABASE1 = ["list of connection dicts"]
SQL_QUERY = "select query"

def fetch_service_status_details(row):
    async def apply(row):
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        user_id = row["user_id"]
        service_id = row["service_id"]

        url = SERVICE_URL + "/" + service_id + "/" + user_id
        # this is the only step which bennefits from asyncio:
        resp = await loop.run_in_executor(
            EXECUTOR,
            partial(requests.get, url, headers=headers, verify=False)
        )
        row["resp_code"] = resp.status_code
        if resp.ok:
            row["has_active_service"] = ...
        else:
            row["has_active_service"] = ...
    # create a new "row" object which is not recycled by Pandas internals:
    fixed_row = current_df.get().loc[row.name]
    apply_tasks.get().add(asyncio.create_task(apply(fixed_row)))

    return None

def connection(connection_dct):
    db = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=connection_dct["host"], user=connection_dct["user"], password=connection_dct["password"], database=connection_dct["database"]
    )
    return db

def generate_df():
    data = pd.DataFrame(columns=["service_id", "user_id"])
    for db in DATABASE1:
        conn = connection(db)
        temp = pd.read_sql(SQL_QUERY, conn)
        data = pd.concat([data, temp])
    return data

async def main():
    data = generate_df()
    current_df.set(data)
    apply_tasks.set(set())
    data = data.apply(fetch_service_status_details, axis=1)
    await asyncio.gather(*apply_tasks.get())
    # here all rows have been operated upon!

    # rest of calculative operations on df
    ...

current_df = contextvars.ContextVar("current_df")
apply_tasks = contextvars.ContextVar("apply_tasks")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    EXECUTOR = ThreadPoolExecutor(20) # for 20 concurrent network connections
    asyncio.run(main())



Both "apply_tasks" and "current_df"  could just be normal global variables - but making then contextvars like above can insure against problems if you ever try to add more concurrent things here.
Also, we are keeping a "row"  object and a task for each row in the dataframe - this should not be a problem if your dataframe is much smaller than your memory amount (say, around 100_000 rows), but could pose a problem when running into the millions of rows: anyway, in this scenario, the overhead adding by using iterrows rather than apply is neglible when compared with the network operations, so one could create some code to fetch data concurrently without using apply.
